# Filter IMPORTHTML data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

When I import data, it comes in this format (*image 1*), with blank spaces. I would like to know if there is any way to adjust so that these blanks disappear, the two models expected (*image 2 and 3*) if there was any way to reach them would be important to me.

Remembering that all dates have `/` and all times have `:`

I tried to filter from `QUERY`, but when trying to `"Select Col1, Col2, Col4 Where Col2 is not null"` the dates disappear and only the times remain, I tried via `REGEXMATCH` to separate the dates from the times using `/` and `:` but also I was not successful.

I also tried it via `IMPORTXML`, but some data ends up not being imported correctly on some pages of the site, for `IMPORTHTML` these errors do not happen. The `XML's` I used were:

`"//tr[@class='no-date-repetition-new' and ..//td[@class='team team-a']] | //tr[@class='no-date-repetition-new live-now' and ..//td[@class='team team-a']]"`
`"//td[@class='team team-a']/a | //td[@class='team team-a strong']/a"`

**The current formula is as follows:**
`=IMPORTHTML("https://int.soccerway.com/national/austria/1-liga/20192020/regular-season/r54328/","table",1)`

**IMPORTHTML Original:**
[image]

**Expected formats:**
[image] --- [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than filtering what you need is to restructure the imported data.

Anyway, I think that the easier solution to get the final result is to use multiple IMPORTXML formulas.

[image]

URL
A1: `https://int.soccerway.com/national/austria/1-liga/20192020/regular-season/r54328/`

Headers
A2: `//table[contains(@class,'matches')]/thead/tr/th`

Day
A3: `//td[contains(@class,'date')]/parent::tr`

Teams and Score
A4: `//td[contains(@class,'team-a')]/parent::tr`

A6: `=transpose(IMPORTXML($A$1,A2))`
A7: `=IMPORTXML($A$1,A3)`
B7: `=IMPORTXML(A1,A4)`

You might want to replace the formula on A6 by static values in order to place them properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can join 2 queries together (one next to the other) in a single formula, to get your results

```
={QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://int.soccerway.com/national/austria/1-liga/20192020/regular-season/r54328/","table",1), 
    "select Col1 where Col2 is null and not Col1 contains '*'",1), 
QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://int.soccerway.com/national/austria/1-liga/20192020/regular-season/r54328/","table",1), 
    "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2 is not null label Col1 'Time'",1)}
```

**How the formula works:**

1. As you notice the data part of both queries is the same in both of them. What is actually different is *"what we ask for from the query"*
2. In the first one we use `"select Col1 where Col2 is null and not Col1 contains '*'"`
3. In the second one `"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2 is not null label Col1 'Time'"`
4. We create an array by joining them together as in `={1stQUERY,2ndQUERY}`

[image]